# how to find if a number is breakable into exactly 2 prime factors?

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to check if a number is breakable into 2 prime factors (exactly 2)
for example 21=7*3
35=5*7
i am unable to figure out any standard procedure for this purpose.
is there any algorithm to do this.?

Comment: Google "integer factorisation".

Comment: The best method to do this depends a lot on the size of your numbers. What is the largest number you want to test?

Comment: @Henry, Constraints are up to `10^6` as per the given constraints of the ongoing contest's [**question**](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/competitive/programming-indiahacks-2017/algorithm/hacker-with-prime-bebe28ac/). :P

Comment: Ok, then just make a trial division with 2 and the odd integers up to the square root of the number. That's at most 500 divisions to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following references.

1. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/
2. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-factorization-using-sieve-olog-n-multiple-queries/

Apart form sieve of eratosthene use segmented sieve, http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exactly-n-distinct-prime-factor-numbers-b/

Comment: Thanks man ...l got that

Comment: Tweak this one a bit http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exactly-n-distinct-prime-factor-numbers-b/

Here use n=2 and print each number that satisfies